# how to reuse value_counts output

Tags: pandas

Can you please tell me how to remove the first column of the output of value_counts and save somewhere? I need to use the result only, e.g., in the output below, I have the dates in the first column and the occurrence count in the second column, now i want to remove the dates so I can use the occurrences somewhere else

This is in Pandas

```
17-06-2017    637
15-06-2017    549
19-06-2017    510
14-06-2017    460
18-06-2017    431
20-06-2017    332
16-06-2017    220
Name: Timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Thanks

I tried a couple of online suggestions, but could not get a direct suggestion

Comment: Result is a pd.Series. Use .values to access values as a numpy array. Generally you don't need to do that though, index (dates) isn't treated as values in pandas operations.